# Why python recursion return None Value

Tags: python, recursion, nonetype

I'm trying to solve some codility task using recursion in Python.
Can someone check this code and tell me why it returns `None`? I want to get `[4, 5]` in the variable called "solution".

```
def rec_fun(upstream,downstream):

    if not upstream or not downstream : 
        if upstream : 

            return  upstream
        if downstream: 
            return downstream
    if upstream[0] >downstream[0] : 
        downstream.pop(0)
    else:
        upstream.pop(0)

    rec_fun(upstream,downstream)


def solution(A, B):

    upstream=[]
    downstream=[]
    n=len(A)
    for i in range(0,n) : 
        if B[i]==0:
            upstream.append(A[i])
        else:
            downstream.append(A[i])
    upstream=sorted(upstream)
    downstream=sorted(downstream)


    return rec_fun(upstream,downstream)


A=[4,3,2,1,5]
B=[0,1,0,0,0]

solution =  solution(A, B)
print solution
```

The output is: `output = None`, it should be `[4, 5]`.

Comment: `return rec_fun(upstream,downstream)`

Answer (score 0):

In your recursive function you are not `return`ing anything. You have to add some `return` statement. Namely:

```
return rec_fun(upstream,downstream)
```

Comment: I have 2 returns return  upstream and  return downstream  ..

Comment: If yo uadd  print here : if upstream : 
            print "return "
            print upstream
            return  upstream     , You will see what I'm talking..

Comment: it works now , tnx