# Why does this happen when using recursion in python?

Tags: python, recursion

I am learning resursion recently and I wrote a simple recursive function to verify my understanding:

```
def hello(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 'hello'
    else:
        print('hello')
        hello(n-1)

def returnhello():
    return 'hello'

print(returnhello())
print()
print(hello(5))
```

the output of this is shown here:

```
hello

hello
hello
hello
hello
None
```

Why the last call in the recursion prints None instead of hello? I was expecting it to print 5 hello

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215141/recursive-function-returning-none-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210646/i-expect-true-but-get-none https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599149/python-recursion-with-list-returns-none https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061245/python-recursion-returning-none-value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739963/recursive-function-returning-none https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340281/python-recursion-return-none-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692143/why-python-recursion-return-none-value

Comment: @Stef please just vote to close questions. If you don't know which one is canonical, ask or discuss in the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python), or try https://sopython.com/canon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right recursion function for your expected output is:

```
def hello(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 'hello'
    else:
        print('hello')
        return hello(n-1)

def returnhello():
    return 'hello'

print(returnhello())
print()
print(hello(5))
```

Also, it can be written as:

```
def hello(n):
    if n==1:
        print("hello")
    else:
        print("hello")
        hello(n-1)
        
def returnhello():
    return 'hello'

print(returnhello())
print()
hello(5)
```

The output will be:

```
hello

hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

**Note:**

You mustn't use **print** with a recursive function, you can use a function with return statement or without any statement.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if you think it's your answer :))

Answer (score 5):

This is because in your `else` part in `hello(n)` you don't have a `return` statement before `hello(n-1)`, so the first call (exiting the last) will return a `None`.

If you put a return before `hello(n-1)` you should get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

@saedx has identified and corrected your issue. Python returns `None` by default and that is what you see printed after the function returns.

You could implement your `hello` function to be a bit more consistent in how it displays the strings. At present the first n-1 are printed in the body of the function but the caller is left to print the final one.

Here the function prints all n of the strings.

```
def hello(n):
    print('hello')
    if n > 1:
        hello(n-1)

hello(5)
```

In this case you just call the function. You don't print what it returns.

The other way would be to have the caller print all n of the strings.

```
def hello(n):
    yield 'hello'
    if n > 1:
        yield from hello(n-1)
```

Which is then called like

```
print('\n'.join(hello(5)))
```

Also note that both these examples remove the duplication of the string being printed. Its worth noting that if you passed in a number less than 1 you'd be in trouble, as it would recurse infinitely. So we could throw an exception in that case.